# NestJs cannot use pg library

Tags: javascript, npm, nestjs, cloudflare, pg

I've tried to add the following webpack config but it doesn't seems to work at all:

```js
import webpack from 'webpack';

module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.plugins.push(
      new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
        resourceRegExp: /^pg-native$|^cloudflare:sockets$/,
      }),
    );

    return config;
  },
};
```

I am using Nest.js v9.4.2 and I want to use pg v8.6.0 library for my project but when I add it to the `package.json` I get the following error:

```
 Info  Webpack is building your sources...

ERROR in cloudflare:sockets
Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "cloudflare:sockets" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "cloudflare:" URIs.
```

Comment: Use `pg v8.10.0` , I had similar issue with `v8.11.0`